Next.js 403 error upstream image response failed
I have set the remotPatterns in next.config.ts:
const nextConfig: NextConfig = {
  images:{
    remotePatterns: [{
      protocol: "https",
      hostname: "**",
    }]
  }
};

and my Image component is like:
<Image
src="https://cdn.midjourney.com/387af603-9e45-41b9-bb68-873229c3b8fe/0_0_384_N.webp?method=shortest&qst=6&quality=15"
height={300}
width={300}
priority={true}
alt=""
/>

but still get the 403 error, is it related to some authenticated issues with Midjourney?

I tried this locally in my own machine with your same exact config and code and couldn't reproduce the error, I'm able to see the image just fine. Are you sure the 403 errors are related to the image? Are you able to access the image directly or just not inside your Next app?

@moonstar-x yes i can directly access the image outside the next js app.

Can you provide some details regarding that 403 error? Can you spot it in the network tab of your browser's developer tools and share it here?

@moonstar-x It looks like Midjourney has banned my IP, i changed an IP and it works finally, thank you!
